# Why is it neccessary to update the VERSION NUMBER of database when adding a new column in schema?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am a learning Android Apps development from Udacity, I was taking the database course where the instructor told that we need to change the DATABASE_VERSION when we change the schema of our database. It confused me a lot but couldn't find any solution. Please, someone explain this to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it necessary to update the VERSION NUMBER of database when
>   adding a new column in schema?

It is not necessary to update the VERSION NUMBER, rather it is a suggested way of introducing structural changes based upon checking the VERSION NUMBER as supplied in the code against the value stored in the **user version** field of the databases file header (4 bytes at offset 60) but not the only way. It's a convenience.

It is only applicable/available if using a subclass(extending) the SQLiteOpenHelper class. You don't need to use such a subclass, as you can use the SQLiteDatabase openDatabase method (in which case the neither **onCreate** or **onUpgrade** (or even the seldom used **onDowngrade**) methods will be invoked or are even available).

You can, with some work, implement alternatives such as a process that checks/compares the structure via the **sqlite_master** table and pragma's against a schema. You could implement a process that uses a table to keep track of structural changes. You could have an empty database and use that as a model (although that could waste disk space).

For example, based upon adding a column, you could have a method that is given the table and the  column definition, it checks to see if the column exists in the table (e.g. by inspecting the result from `PRAGMA table_info`) and if not it then applies the **ALTER**ations.

Generally the confusion lies not with **onUpgrade** method but with a mis-conception about the **onCreate** method. That is the **onCreate** method does not run every time the App is run, the **onCreate** method only runs automatically when the database is created, which is once unless the database is then deleted (in which case it will run again).

- The confusion may well stem from people often seeing **onCreate** method in an activity being used to initialse/setup values.

As such an App may need a means of introducing structural changes because **onCreate** won't be run (unless forced e.g. like the commonly used call to **onCreate** method from within the **onUpgrade** method).

### Demonstration

- The code, which works as a basic App, changes the database structure
  each time the App is run to simulate a number of releases (first 4
  runs then the structure will be stable).
- It's not intended to be used in a real App.
- Most of the structure changes are not done via the **onUpgrade**
  method. However, the fourth run does change the structure (adds a
  column to a table) via the **onUpgrade** method.

The Database Helper (subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper) :-

```
public class TestDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "testdb";

    public static final String TBNAME_001 = "test001_table";
    public static final String TBNAME_002 = "test002_table";
    public static final String TBNAME_003 = "test003_table";
    public static final String COL_NAME = "name_column";
    public static final String COL_EXTRA = "extra_cxolumn";

    String TAG = "TESTDBHLPR";

    public TestDBHelper(Context context) {
        //<<<<<<<<<<Note gets database version according to value in MainActivity>>>>>>>>>>
        super(context, DBNAME, null, MainActivity.getDatabaseVersion());
        Log.d(TAG,"CONSTRUCTOR invoked.");
        this.getWritableDatabase(); //<<<<< Force  database open
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(TAG,"ONCREATE invoked.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int old_version, int new_version) {
        Log.d(TAG,"ONUPGRADE invoked. " +
                "\n\tOld version (valued stored in DB) is " + String.valueOf(old_version) +
                "\n\tNew version (as coded in the App) is " + String.valueOf(new_version)
        );
        if (new_version == 2) {
            db.execSQL(getAlterSQl(TBNAME_003));
        }
    }

    public static String getAlterSQl(String table_name) {
        return "ALTER TABLE " + table_name + " ADD COLUMN " + COL_EXTRA + " TEXT";
    }
}
```

- Note that **onCreate** does nothing other than write output to the Log.

  - The table(s) will be progressively added, each time the App is run.
- **onUpgrade** will only do something when the version number is changed to 2.
- The getAlterSQL method simply returns a String ***ALTER TABLE ????? ADD COLUMN EXTRA TEXT***
- Note how the database version is obtained from the MainActivity (so that the version can be changed on the fly for demonstration).

The following is the code for the invoking activity **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TestDBHelper mDBHlpr; //<<<<<<<<<< Declare the Database Helper (will at this stage be NULL)
    Context mContext;
    static int mDatabaseVersion = 1; //<<<<<<<<<< DBVERSION can be changed on the fly
    String TAG = "MAINACTIVITY";

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;

        addNewTable(); //<<<<<<<<<< update database structure if needed

        Log.d(TAG,"Instantiating the Database helper");
        mDBHlpr = new TestDBHelper(this);
        logDBInfo(mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase());
    }

    public static int getDatabaseVersion() {
        return mDatabaseVersion;
    }

    private void addNewTable() {
        String TAG = "ADDNEWTABLE";
        File db_file = this.getDatabasePath(TestDBHelper.DBNAME);
        if (!db_file.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Database doesn't exist so exiting.");
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"Database file exists. Checking for table");
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
                this.getDatabasePath(TestDBHelper.DBNAME).getPath(),
                null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE,
                null
        );
        Log.d(TAG,"Writing Database info (if any) as before any changes");
        logDBInfo(db);
        Log.d(TAG,"Database existed and has been opened");
        String whereclause = "type='table' AND tbl_name LIKE 'test%'";
        Cursor csr = db.query("sqlite_master",null,whereclause,null,null,null,null);
        int row_count = csr.getCount();
        Log.d(TAG,"Extracted " + String.valueOf(row_count) + " application tables");
        csr.close();
        String table_name = "x"; //<<<<<
        switch (row_count) {
            case 0:
                table_name = TestDBHelper.TBNAME_001;
                break;
            case 1:
                table_name = TestDBHelper.TBNAME_002;
                Log.d(TAG,"Adding column " + TestDBHelper.COL_EXTRA + " to table " + TestDBHelper.TBNAME_001);
                db.execSQL(TestDBHelper.getAlterSQl(TestDBHelper.TBNAME_001));
                break;
            case 2:
                table_name = TestDBHelper.TBNAME_003;
                mDatabaseVersion = 2; //<<<<<<<<<< Force onUpgrade
                break;
            default:
                mDatabaseVersion = 2;
        }
        if (table_name.length() < 2) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Database exists but nothing to do");
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"Creating table " + table_name);
        String crt_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + table_name + "(" +
                TestDBHelper.COL_NAME + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_sql);
        Log.d(TAG,"Writing Database info (if any) as after any changes");
        logDBInfo(db);
        db.close();
    }

    private void logDBInfo(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String TAG = "DBINFO";
        Cursor csr = db.query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            String type = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("type"));
            String table_name = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("tbl_name"));
            Log.d(TAG,"Type is " + type + " for table " + table_name);
            if (type.equals("table")) {
                Cursor csr2 = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info(" + table_name + ")",null);
                while (csr2.moveToNext()) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"\n\tTable has a column named " + csr.getString(csr2.getColumnIndex("name")));
                }
                csr2.close();
            }
        }
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

When the App is run before instantiating the Database Helper the **addNewTable** method is run.

The **addNewTable** method does different things according what exists in the database.

#### First time run

If it's the first time the App is run (or database has been deleted/ app uninstalled) then the method simply returns.

The database is then created when the Database Helper is instantiated (by `this.getWritableDatabase(); //<<<<< Force  database open`).

As such the **onCreate** method is invoked, but it doesn't do anything structure wise.

Finally the logDBInfo method is called which list the tables (note when the database is created table **android_metadata** is created so this is listed, this is an Android specific table which contains the locale and can generally be ignored).

The log (due to quite a bit of logging added) shows :-

```
11-02 18:45:02.689 2066-2066/axtest.axtest D/ADDNEWTABLE: Database doesn't exist so exiting.
11-02 18:45:02.689 2066-2066/axtest.axtest D/MAINACTIVITY: Instantiating the Database helper
11-02 18:45:02.689 2066-2066/axtest.axtest D/TESTDBHLPR: CONSTRUCTOR invoked.
11-02 18:45:02.701 2066-2066/axtest.axtest D/TESTDBHLPR: ONCREATE invoked.
11-02 18:45:02.701 2066-2066/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO: Type is table for table android_metadata
11-02 18:45:02.701 2066-2066/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named locale
```

#### Second Run

As the database now exists when **addNewTable** is invoked it does not return, instead it opens the database (**not using the Database helper**), then logs the database info (before any changes are applied).

It then runs a query on the **sqlite_master** table (an SQLite internal/system table with data about items) and extracts rows for tables that start with **test** (there will be none as the only tables that exist are **sqlite_master** and **android_metadata**).

The number of rows, which equates, to the number of tables is obtained. For this second run it will be 0.

The switch/case sets the table name accordingly, for this run to the value held by the constant **TABLE001**, which is (as the resultant value's length is greater than 1) then used to create the table.

After the table has been created the Database information is logged, now showing the new table and the database is closed.

The database helper is then instantiated, **onCreate** is not called as the database now exists, **onUpgrade** is not called as the version will be 1. Finally the database information is logged.

The log shows :-

```
11-02 18:46:16.009 2109-2109/axtest.axtest D/ADDNEWTABLE: Database file exists. Checking for table
11-02 18:46:16.013 2109-2109/axtest.axtest D/ADDNEWTABLE: Writing Database info (if any) as before any changes
11-02 18:46:16.013 2109-2109/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO: Type is table for table android_metadata
11-02 18:46:16.013 2109-2109/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named locale
11-02 18:46:16.013 2109-2109/axtest.axtest D/ADDNEWTABLE: Database existed and has been opened
11-02 18:46:16.013 2109-2109/axtest.axtest D/ADDNEWTABLE: Extracted 0 application tables
11-02 18:46:16.013 2109-2109/axtest.axtest D/ADDNEWTABLE: Creating table test001_table
11-02 18:46:16.021 2109-2109/axtest.axtest D/ADDNEWTABLE: Writing Database info (if any) as after any changes
11-02 18:46:16.021 2109-2109/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO: Type is table for table android_metadata
11-02 18:46:16.021 2109-2109/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named locale
11-02 18:46:16.021 2109-2109/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO: Type is table for table test001_table
11-02 18:46:16.021 2109-2109/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named name_column
11-02 18:46:16.021 2109-2109/axtest.axtest D/MAINACTIVITY: Instantiating the Database helper
11-02 18:46:16.021 2109-2109/axtest.axtest D/TESTDBHLPR: CONSTRUCTOR invoked.
11-02 18:46:16.021 2109-2109/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO: Type is table for table android_metadata
11-02 18:46:16.021 2109-2109/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named locale
11-02 18:46:16.021 2109-2109/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO: Type is table for table test001_table
11-02 18:46:16.021 2109-2109/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named name_column
```

#### Third Run

This is similar to the 2nd run, other than that **test002_table** is added, rather than test001_table, and that table **tes001_table** has a **column added** named **extra_column**.

The log shows :-

```
11-02 18:50:13.925 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/ADDNEWTABLE: Database file exists. Checking for table
11-02 18:50:13.929 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/ADDNEWTABLE: Writing Database info (if any) as before any changes
11-02 18:50:13.933 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO: Type is table for table android_metadata
11-02 18:50:13.933 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named locale
11-02 18:50:13.933 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO: Type is table for table test001_table
11-02 18:50:13.933 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named name_column
11-02 18:50:13.933 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/ADDNEWTABLE: Database existed and has been opened
11-02 18:50:13.933 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/ADDNEWTABLE: Extracted 1 application tables
11-02 18:50:13.937 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/ADDNEWTABLE: Adding column extra_column to table test001_table
11-02 18:50:13.937 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/ADDNEWTABLE: Creating table test002_table
11-02 18:50:13.941 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/ADDNEWTABLE: Writing Database info (if any) as after any changes
11-02 18:50:13.941 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO: Type is table for table android_metadata
11-02 18:50:13.941 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named locale
11-02 18:50:13.941 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO: Type is table for table test001_table
11-02 18:50:13.941 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named name_column
11-02 18:50:13.941 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named extra_column
11-02 18:50:13.941 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO: Type is table for table test002_table
11-02 18:50:13.941 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named name_column
11-02 18:50:13.941 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/MAINACTIVITY: Instantiating the Database helper
11-02 18:50:13.941 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/TESTDBHLPR: CONSTRUCTOR invoked.
11-02 18:50:13.945 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO: Type is table for table android_metadata
11-02 18:50:13.945 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named locale
11-02 18:50:13.945 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO: Type is table for table test001_table
11-02 18:50:13.945 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named name_column
11-02 18:50:13.945 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named extra_column
11-02 18:50:13.945 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO: Type is table for table test002_table
11-02 18:50:13.945 2160-2160/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named name_column
```

#### The Fourth Run

The fourth run adds another table namely **test003_table** BUT now changes the database version from 1 to 2 before the Database Helper is instantiated and thus finally causes the **onUpGrade** method to be called, this alters the **test003_table** by adding a column, namely **extra_column**

The log shows :-

```
11-02 18:57:00.589 2230-2230/? D/ADDNEWTABLE: Database file exists. Checking for table
11-02 18:57:00.593 2230-2230/? D/ADDNEWTABLE: Writing Database info (if any) as before any changes
11-02 18:57:00.593 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO: Type is table for table android_metadata
11-02 18:57:00.593 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named locale
11-02 18:57:00.593 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO: Type is table for table test001_table
11-02 18:57:00.593 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named name_column
11-02 18:57:00.593 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named extra_column
11-02 18:57:00.593 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO: Type is table for table test002_table
11-02 18:57:00.593 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named name_column
11-02 18:57:00.593 2230-2230/? D/ADDNEWTABLE: Database existed and has been opened
11-02 18:57:00.593 2230-2230/? D/ADDNEWTABLE: Extracted 2 application tables
11-02 18:57:00.593 2230-2230/? D/ADDNEWTABLE: Creating table test003_table
11-02 18:57:00.597 2230-2230/? D/ADDNEWTABLE: Writing Database info (if any) as after any changes
11-02 18:57:00.597 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO: Type is table for table android_metadata
11-02 18:57:00.597 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named locale
11-02 18:57:00.597 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO: Type is table for table test001_table
11-02 18:57:00.597 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named name_column
11-02 18:57:00.597 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named extra_column
11-02 18:57:00.597 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO: Type is table for table test002_table
11-02 18:57:00.597 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named name_column
11-02 18:57:00.597 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO: Type is table for table test003_table
11-02 18:57:00.597 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named name_column
11-02 18:57:00.597 2230-2230/? D/MAINACTIVITY: Instantiating the Database helper
11-02 18:57:00.597 2230-2230/? D/TESTDBHLPR: CONSTRUCTOR invoked.
11-02 18:57:00.601 2230-2230/? D/TESTDBHLPR: ONUPGRADE invoked. 
        Old version (valued stored in DB) is 1
        New version (as coded in the App) is 2
11-02 18:57:00.605 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO: Type is table for table android_metadata
11-02 18:57:00.605 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named locale
11-02 18:57:00.605 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO: Type is table for table test001_table
11-02 18:57:00.605 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named name_column
11-02 18:57:00.605 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named extra_column
11-02 18:57:00.605 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO: Type is table for table test002_table
11-02 18:57:00.605 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named name_column
11-02 18:57:00.605 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO: Type is table for table test003_table
11-02 18:57:00.605 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named name_column
11-02 18:57:00.605 2230-2230/? D/DBINFO:    Table has a column named extra_column
```

Subsequent runs would then use the final structure and database version 2.

- If the default of the switch/case construct did not set the version to 2 and thus version 1 were used, it would fail because there is no **onDownGrade** method defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was quite helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Imagine this scenario:

1. You created an initial version of your app.
2. People installed your app and when the database was first used, method `onCreate()` was executed and Android created the database on internal memory (test.db for example).
3. Now, you created a new feature which requires a new column (you changed the schema).
4. New users which will install the new version of your app would be fine because `onCreate` will be executed with this new column.
5. However, what about the old users who already had their database created on the file system?

That's why you need a mechanism to update the database. Because in the new version of your app, you have SQL queries for that new database schema. You have queries using that new column. However, old users still have an old version of your database. So, that new column does not exist to them yet.

Update mechanism is somehow simple: Every time you need to upgrade your database, just increase the database version. Android will automatically check the database version on the file system. If installed version is old than the current database, `onUpdate()` will be invoked and then, you can update the way you want:

- You can just delete old tables and create a new one.
- You can create a new column without deleting the old data.
- Etc... This will vary from project to project... It will vary according to your necessity. You may never used, for example.

If you did not release your APK yet, you don't need to change the database version (because no one installed your app yet). Just keep making the changes that you need. However, after the app is released, you always have to take extra care with the database version and how it is updated... You always have to simulated tests with a fresh install and simulate an user which is updating the app...

Answer (score 0):

Basically speaking, to change the database schema in Android the onUpgrade() method of your SQLHelper class must be called, and you must perform all the changes to the database schema there. Increasing the database version number tells the system that there are changes to the database schema (e.g. new table column) and it will trigger the OnUpgrade() method of your SQLHelper class.

Here is an example on how to use the database version number. Suppose our current database version is 4.

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion > 1) {
         // the code to upgrade from our initial database to v2
    }
    if (oldVersion > 2) {
         // the code to upgrade from v2 to v3
    }
    if (oldVersion > 3) {
         // the code to upgrade from v3 to v4
    }
}
```

So now, if the application is reinstalled, the onUpgrade() will be called if user's current db version was lower then 3. And having the old db version of user's database, we can adequately migrate to new database schema without using any data.

Answer (score 0):

You must always change the version if you have added columns to a table (for example).

In some cases, however (testing only for new features or if you do not care about losing old data) you can also force onUpgrade () to delete everything and recreate it totally new recall onCreate().

But the real sense it's:

```
   @Override
    public void onUpgrade( SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion ) 
    {
      if (oldVersion<2)
         {
         database.execSQL(myQueryAlignment)
         }
    }
```

To simulate an update (check for example if your script works) is possible
using ADV, delete the database on the emulator, insert the old database and
reinstall the APK ... this way (if the database version has been increased in the new apk) it will run onUpdate () in an "artificial" way.